# What are the scales and wings for on Captain America's costume?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Captain America's costume features wings on the temples and scale-like things on the top half of the torso. I have often wondered, what are the point of these items? My guess is that the wings are intended to represent a bald eagle's wings, but their wings are in reality brown. I have no idea what the scales are for. Are they armor? I'm not sure.

[image: The Avengers comic front cover featuring Cap, Thor, Tony, and Janet]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The scaled part of his costume [is indeed meant to be armor](https://www.cbr.com/captain-america-scale-mail-costume-history/).

> Therefore, clearly Joe Simon was looking towards a knight-like design for his new patriotic hero, Captain America, when he sat down to design him over a year before the United States entered World War II. Note Simon even specifically writes "mailed armor" in the design...

[image: Sketch proposal for Captain America]

This is "[scale armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_armour)", which is technically different from "[mail armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_mail)", although there do exist examples of scale armor built by attaching scales to chain mail.

I haven't found a canonical statement on the wings, but it is likely that they hearken to depictions of Mercury with his [winged helmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_helmet), creating a connotation of extreme speed. The Flash is an example from DC comics of the same costume symboolism.

Comment: Possible meaning for the wings is "freedom of though" as was the intent of the "Mercury" dime obverse.

Comment: The wings were definitely a more popular costume design element back in the [Golden Age of Comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Comic_Books). Note them on Thor's head in the OQ's picture as well.